# Does Matlab Parallel Computing Toolbox consume other licenses (e.g. image processing)?

Tags: matlab

consider the following code:

```
matlabpool 10;

parfor i=1:10
    img = imread(foo(i));
end
```

the cluster is set up using sge. My question is whether this code will consume further matlab basic and image processing toolbox licenses for each of the workers?

thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parallel Computing Toolbox allows you to use on the cluster licences that you have on your MATLAB client. In your case, you're using SGE, therefore you are using [MDCS](http://www.mathworks.com/products/distriben/) licences on the workers. Each worker process consumes only a single MDCS worker licence, but is permitted to use all products for which your client is licensed.

Comment: You are talking about "distributed computing tolbox" the question is about "parallel computing toolbox"

Comment: @Ali: as far as I understand: the client where you send jobs must have the parallel computing toolbox. the location where the jobs are sent must have the distributed computing server. so the two are very related

Comment: @Ali: YCHAI is completely correct, the workers in this case are using MDCS licences.

Comment: I didn't know that you need Par.Comp. Licence to use Dist. Comp. servers. The way I use it, on an 8 core machine, I have Par.Comp. and I use parfor to run parallel for loops.

Comment: @Ali: Right, you can use the local scheduler if you have only PCT; if you have PCT + MDCS, you can use other schedulers such as SGE - which the OP is using.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the Parallel Computing Toolbox alone, then `parfor` will run up to 8 parallel processes on a single machine, thus consume only one license each of the additional toolboxes (since Matlab licenses are checked out per machine per user; a single user running two instances of Matlab on a single machine only consumes one license).

If you use the Distributed Computing Server toolbox, one license for each toolbox will be checked out [per person per job](http://www.mathworks.com/products/distriben/description3.html), so if you want to run two jobs on the cluster (with any number of workers each), you'll need two of each toolbox licenses.

**EDIT**
@Edric points out that you can quit the client after submitting the job, which means that the additional toolbox licenses are freed. Thus, as long as you have enough Distributed Computing Server licenses to run all your workers, you could run as many parallel jobs as you want.

Comment: This is not quite right. The (non-local) workers consume only MDCS worker licences and nothing else.

Comment: @Edric: So you're saying that if you start a MDCS job, all you need is a MDCS license per worker, but you do not need any other license in order to run the entire job? Because what I said was that *if you run two jobs, you need two of each licenses each*, not *two times the number of workers*.

Comment: @Jonas: the submitting client needs only MATLAB+PCT+relevant toolbox licences, the workers need only MDCS licences. So, if you quit your client after submission, the only licences in use are MDCS even if the job uses e.g. Image Processing Toolbox on the workers.

Comment: @Edric: Thanks for the answer. That would be great actually. Do you have any reference to support your comment?

Comment: @YCAI This page http://www.mathworks.com/products/distriben/supported/sched/license_management.html states "The only type of license required on your computer cluster is the MATLAB Distributed Computing Server worker license."

Comment: @Edric: I wasn't aware that you can quit the client after submitting the job. I've fixed my answer.